# Ruby on rails - Disable cache from specific div inside a cached div

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

In my application I use `cache expires_in: 5.minutes` to cache `.cached` *div* in my view *(this works fine)*, Inside `.cached` *div*  you can find `.vote_div` *div*.

*Here is what I have:*

```
- cache expires_in: 5.minutes do
  .col-xs-12.cached
     %h4= @image.title
     .img-body-vote
       %span= @image.body

       // DONT WANT TO CACHE THIS VOTE DIV
       .vote_div
         %p= @vote_counts
         = link_to 'vote', vote_path
```

As you can see I **cache** `.cached` and inside this *div*, there is a *div* called `.vote_div` that I don't want to `cache` at all (since it gives wrong number for `@vote_counts`).

How can I disable `cache` for `.vote_div`?

Comment: don't worry about it being cached: inject the value via javascript. afaik you'll not be able to achieve what you want with the rails template caching mechanism

Comment: Thanks @SaschaKaestle Could you please give me a example for how to injecting via javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of *rails template caching mechanism*, the code is not able to `cache: false` or `cache: true` some part inside `- cache expires_in: 5.minutes do`.

Best option would be re-organizing the view.

```
.col-xs-12
  - cache expires_in: 5.minutes do
    .col-xs-12.cached
       %h4= @image.title
       .img-body-vote
         %span= @image.body

  .vote_div
    %p= @vote_counts
    = link_to 'vote', vote_path
```